# Can an element in a heterogenous array know what templated type it is?

Tags: c++, class, templates, virtual, rtti

I want to create a whole bunch of objects in an array, and I want them to be different templated types. The objective is that I want to update each of these objects and store the variable value they hold as a string. For example:

```
template <typename T> struct VariableToString
{
    VariableToString(T& varArg) : variable(varArg){};
    T& variable;
    std::string variableAsString;

    void update()
    {
       variableAsString = std::to_string(variable); // <--- Compiler knows which overloaded function to call, but not through a pointer to this struct at runtime
    }
}
```

I then want to have an std::vector of these objects, so I can iterate through all the objects and convert the variable values to string. I'm not sure how/if I can do this. Basically something like this:

```
std::vector<Idontknow*> myVector;
for (auto i : myVector) i->update();
```

Usually you would have a vector of pointers to base class and let virtualisation handle which function to call. But in this case I was wondering if it can be handled based on the type of the template. I thought about RTTI, would that be able to identify what type "variable" is and call the appropriate to_string() function?

Will I have to just create a new derived version for each one? Like:

```
struct BaseClass
{
    virtual void update() = 0;
}

struct DoubleToString : BaseClass
{
    double& variable
    void update() override;
} 

std::vector<BaseClass*> myVector;
for (auto i : myVector) i->update();
```

Comment: No. There is no such thing as "type of the template" or "templated type" or any such thing.

Comment: If your type depends on a base class, there is nothing special for templates. An instance of a template is simply a type. The object of that type must not know abut the template type it is build from. For your design it looks simply to derive from a common base class and simply do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep you derived class templated:

```
struct BaseClass
{
   virtual void update() = 0;
}
template <typename T> struct VariableToString : BaseClass{/*...*/}
```

Then you can use it the way you wanted:

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> myVector;
/*...*/
for (auto i : myVector) i->update();
```

Though consider using a smart pointer instead, e.g.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>> myVector;
/*...*/
for (auto i : myVector) i->update();
```

Or use `shared_ptr<>` instead of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Of course, I missed it and it was so obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have simply a template class it is quite easy to do the job. But also if your template is a wrapper for any other class, you can use it as long as it is derived from a common base class to get the right virtual method called. This has nothing to do with RTTI!

Using a wrapper makes it possible to use classes which have no common base class. And you also can specialize your wrapper for classes, which have a function with the same semantic but different name and signature.

```
class Base
{
    public:
        virtual std::string ToString() = 0;

        virtual ~Base() {}
};

class A
{
    public:
        std::string GetString() { return "From Type A"; }
};

class B
{
    public:
        std::string GetString() { return "From Type B"; }
};


class C
{   
    public:
        void Name(std::string& name)
        {
            name="From Type C";
        }   
};  

template < typename Inner >
class Wrapper: public Base, Inner
{   
    public:
        std::string ToString() override { return Inner::GetString(); } 
};  

template <>
class Wrapper<C>: public Base, C
{   
    public:
        std::string ToString() override 
        {
            std::string name;
            C::Name(name);
            return name;
        }   
};  

int main()
{   
    std::vector< Base*> elements;

    elements.push_back( new Wrapper<A>);
    elements.push_back( new Wrapper<B>);
    elements.push_back( new Wrapper<C>);

    for ( auto& el: elements )
    {   
        std::cout << el->ToString() << std::endl;
    }   

    for ( auto& el: elements )
    {   
        delete el; 
    }

}
```